# XML Binding via Web Service (or JAXB)

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, xml-serialization

I have to maintain a Java EE 5 web app.
A part of this app is the exchange of messages through web services (with WSDL contract).
The wsdl is used to generate the Java classes through the Eclipse wsdl2Java (I think it uses Axis)

Now I have to implement a modification where the server that we call via Web Service must be able to respond in an async way.
In fact the server will not respond immediately with the SOAP message response but, after a while, call a web service exposed by the client (our web app) 
passing the SOAP Message response of the first call as a field (parameter) of this second Web service invocation.
The client then will save the SOAP response (or XML) in a file.

- Is there a way to populate the already generated Java classes using this XML or SOAP message file? I mean a way to simulate the direct response of the server (feeding the Axis binding Stub)

  I have also tried to use JAXB (to bind XML to JAVA) but since the SOAP message response is complex, when I call JAXBContext I receive an error:

  ```
  CodPrestazione does not have a no-arg default constructor
  ```

  since this class is an enum class generated by the wsdl2Java.
- Is there a way to bypass this error without annotating or modifying the java class (this class is generated so I will be forced to modify this class at every re-generation)?
- What is the best way to consume a saved SOAP message file(or XML)? Alternatively, how can I deserialize SOAP using Axis 1.3?